# Can other members see old versions of my user profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

I had a strange comment on a [question I posted](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/590863/218819). The user referred to something that had been in my profile a few weeks ago, but which wasn't there when I posted the question.  I'm curious how the user might have been able to view old versions of my profile.

Apparently something about my spelling proclivities, or the way I phrased it grated with this user.  Here's what he said:

[image: user refers to my old profile]

I couldn't tell you what it was that I had originally said in my profile page because I wrote it years ago, forgot about it, and recently got rid of it.

It's a bit disconcerting that people might be able to view things I wrote about myself but then thought better of.  I find it very difficult to judge what is an appropriate tone, and it sometimes takes me more than one attempt to come up with something I'm happy with.  I'd feel safer in this community if I knew that edits to my profile were not visible to other users.  I understand that moderators sometimes need to view a chain of events, but I think the user in question is not a moderator.

Comment: The (deliberate?) misspelling of "spelling" (could be a reference to word differences like [travelling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/travelling#Alternative_forms) vs. [traveling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/traveling#Verb) and [modeled](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/modeled#Verb) vs. [modelled](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/modelled#Verb)) might have set them off. In any case, the pandemic was [a devastating blow to the exceptionalism](https://thedispatch.com/p/covid-19-and-the-failure-of-swedish).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is obviously pretty offensive to say:

> Also, I'm English, so my spelling of words like "serialise" may grate with people who are used to US speling.

Your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/507862/outstandingbill) still has it in its full glory.

I love the grating. The behaviour of those non-English speakers need to change.

(click *Update profile info* to update your network profile)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I've fixed it now. I'm finding it difficult to judge your tone here. That's probably my autism. Would you mind helping me out and explaining why it's offensive?  I spell stuff the English way, and in the past people have pulled me up on it. Why is it offensive to say this?

Comment: @OutstandingBill I don't think it is offensive at all (hence my obviously). Some people from some countries think they are the center of the world and get to set all the standards. It is often a surprise to them other countries, believes, language, spelling, courtesy rules exist. I don't think your statement was offensive, as a matter of fact, I take it as a precautionary applogee which I find thoughtful of you. I wouldn't be bothered too much by these events. If it is unclear what is written it might get edited, sometimes into US spelling which is not needed but not a big deal either.

Comment: That's a big relief. Thank you. That's a very good way of putting it - a precautionary apology.

Comment: *"I spell stuff the English way"* - But... that's still wrong, while -ize is most certainly the AmE way, both -ize and -ise are acceptable in BrE and it's (often) dependent on the ending of the root Greek word. Saying your way is "_the_ English way" is simply incorrect.

Comment: @Nick let's settle on that all non US speakers spell *an* English way foremost to grate US spelling purists ...

Comment: @Nick, I choose to spell the way I do because it's the way I was taught at school in the '70s.  Things may have changed since then, and "~ize" might be gaining popularity.  But please don't accuse me of claiming that "~ize" is incorrect though, because I didn't.  Perhaps it's also worth noting that I must have had my tongue in my cheek when I wrote it because I cheekily missed out one of the Ls in "US speling", a reference to "canceling" vs. "cancelling".

Comment: @OutstandingBill I was just quoting what you said in your comment above: *"the English way"*... "the" _is_ singular after all, I read it as you implying all others are incorrect. No offence meant.

Comment: @Nick, I see your point and stand corrected. In my mind, BrE and AmE don't neatly occupy "different" language" or "same language" status. It's evidently difficult to navigate.

Answer (score 8):

While Cody is technically correct, the answer isn't no. It's maybe.

While Stack Overflow doesn't show your "about me" revision history, there are still various caches and archives that can - including archive.org, [which captured a few of these for you](https://web.archive.org/web/20190226030004/https://stackoverflow.com/users/1294318/outstandingbill), including what I think is the revision that sparked the comment (which is the one I linked to). There's no guarantee an arbitrary profile is in the internet archive though, because it requires manual inclusion At Some Point™ (though anyone can do it -- it's more likely the more traffic your profile receives, but it doesn't happen automatically and is consequently not a guarantee).

Got ninja'd by rene's more likely answer, but the internet archive is a possible source, though substantially less likely than the Stack Exchange profile.

But to echo Cody's statement, the comment is definitely flag-worthy.

Comment: Happy to ninja you ...

Comment: That really is going the extra mile.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

**No**, a revision history of your user profile's "about me" section is *not* visible publicly on Stack Exchange sites.

In fact, such a revision history is not even visible to moderators. All we can see is that you made an edit to it at some particular point in time, not what you changed. (I am not 100% sure whether staff can see the revision history, but I very much doubt it, considering that it isn't even displayed to the owner of the profile. This suggests that the history isn't tracked in a database at all.)

However, since user profile pages are public, it *is* possible that some sort of crawler had archived an old version of your profile page. I don't know, and I don't feel like doing a "deep dive" on your user name to find out! (Update: [Zoe did the research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412311).)

I would recommend flagging such comments as "unfriendly/unkind", if you haven't already. Making fun of someone based on their regional spelling is definitely unfriendly, not to mention weird. That's never a valid basis for someone to choose not to answer a question. I wouldn't put much more thought into this particular interaction.

Comment: Slightly related (as this could spill over into editing): *[What should the standard spelling be - British or US?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869)*